# What is the best way to handle a player planning to go off piste?

Tags: gm-techniques, critical-role-show

At the culmination of the Critical Roll campaign, in an act that has now become canon in DnD Joe Manganiello's character Arkhan

> attaches the Hand of Vecna to himself and teleports away.

This is a great example of a player planning out and doing something that acts to betray the group and has the potential to throw a campaign. I am unsure exactly to what extent Matt the DM was aware up front as to Joe's intentions from things I have read I think he was aware of the goals of the player, and the reason for joining and helping the party while not being aware of the specifics of the plan.

However it leads to a wider question for me, as a DM what is the best way to ensure players keep you updated as to any secret plans, while also ensuring the freedom to do what they want when they want?

I am not talking here about the random events that throw a campaign on its head, your players kill a key NPC, talk there way into a meeting you didn't think they would see or go to that village on the map you had no intention for them to get to yet. I am talking about a pre-meditated planned act by a player at least in some essence in secret to the other players? Personally I have asked my players to run anything regarding background, secrets or plans past me, not in order for me to say yes or no, but to allow me to talk to them DM to Player to help them think about the potential repercussions, gaps etc, but I wonder if even that is too firm a hand to have considering my role (as I see it) is to create a playground in which my players can have fun.

Comment: Have taken comments on board, asked the original question on Reddit and rephrased this to get to the heart of my question here to the community

Comment: For anybody confused about "off piste" like I was, it means "[to do something different than what is normal or expected](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/go-off-piste)" TIL!

Comment: While this may not be off-topic anymore, it is still heavily POB.

Comment: @Szega I'm not sure about opnin-based, but it's borderline. It's stranger in that OP is not experiencing the issue, has a method to avoid it, but is still asking about it. The range of answers could be anything from "my table totally allows this and it's fine" to every variation beyond that all the way up to "we don't allow secrets at all." Maybe it is POB...

Comment: @Rubiksmoose Ahhh....I knew I'd heard the word before but I have to admit my first thoughts were that the player had left the game...unhappy.